# Can a Pokémon 'join' from nowhere in the Pokéwalker?

Tags: pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver, pokemon-hgss-pokewalker

I'm currently playing Pokémon HG/SS with a Pokéwalker. One day I was transferring my Pokémon from the Pokéwalker back into the game and maybe like a couple of minutes later a Pokémon appeared. In this case, it was a Geodude, and it joined like I'd captured it, which I hadn't, and it's still here, on my Pokéwalker, **is this normal?**

Edit: *I didn't have any Pokémon, item or anything else on the Pokéwalker when this one appeared.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if you go walking with a Pokewalker that has no Pokémon there is a chance that a Pokémon will join you and follow you around. You will be able to import this Pokémon into your game.

From [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9walker#Gameplay_and_features):

> The Pokéwalker can be used without a Pokémon stored in it, as well. It
>   will continue to accumulate steps and watts. The Dowsing Machine can
>   still be used, but the Poké Radar cannot, as no battle could take
>   place. In addition, Pokémon from the route being walked may
>   voluntarily join in the Pokéwalker seemingly at random, taking the
>   spot of the missing Pokémon, essentially being caught for free.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, this is a normal occurrence. [According to Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9walker#Gameplay_and_features),

> Pokémon from the route being walked may voluntarily join in the Pokéwalker seemingly at random, taking the spot of the missing Pokémon, essentially being caught for free.